# Oracle apex redirect page if page item a certain value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Trying to create my own authentication since the Authentication scheme in apex won't work properly for what I am trying to do.

basically I have a function to assign the value of a PAGE ITEM either 0 or 1 and

I tried to create a branch wherein I put the above condition if the PAGE ITEM != 1
then it would redirect to another page.

the problem is the point, i tried to have it run before the header but it wont work.

Am I doing anything wrong + any solution for this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Would you provide details/screenshot of your server side condition, so we can check the configuration? And when/what page you're setting/checking your page item?